# How to rename a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

The code that  i tried is

```
ALTER TABLE "STUDENT" RENAME COLUMN "Roll" TO "Num";
```

Its syntax is correct but it shows a error. Whats the problem?

> Error
>
> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "TO" at position 47)
>   SQL query: Copy

```
ALTER TABLE "STUDENT" RENAME COLUMN "column 1" TO "column 2"
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"STUDENT" RENAME COLUMN "column 1" TO "column 2"' at line 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
 ALTER TABLE "STUDENT" RENAME COLUMN "Roll" TO "Num" datatype(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62051/alter-table-rename-a-column) for an answer to your question.

Basically: use backticks instead of quotes.